# Java Writing to file user input from widget

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im really struggling with learning Java and its not going to well. Im hoping to get a bit of help with the following problem.

Im trying to:

1. Get User Input from Widget
2. Save the Input Data to file when button is clicked

My Interface looks like this:

My code looks like this
[image]

```
Button butAddModule = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnS2Add);
butAddModule.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View V){

        //assign  input data from widgets to variable
        EditText varModuleCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtModuleCode);
        EditText varAssDate1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAsgnmnt1Date);
        EditText varAssDate2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAsgnmnt2Date);
        EditText varAssDate3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAsgnmnt3Date);

        //combine input into single variable
        String newModuleInfo =varModuleCode+" "+varAssDate1+" "+varAssDate2+" "+varAssDate3+" ";

        //create file
        String fileName ="write.txt";

        //write to file
        try {
            PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            outputStream.println(newModuleInfo);//Write userInput to file
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

});//end but 1
```

My problem:
The file write.txt is not created. In fact nothing happens with the above code...What am I missing / doing wrong here?

Comment: "Asgnmnt" should be "Assignment".

Comment: its abbreviated...thanks for your constructive input

Comment: Have a look here at internal and external storage: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html